# Multiple Morris graphics not working

Tags: jquery, graphics, morris.js

I'm using Morris.js plugin to use some graphics. I need a page with various Donuts graphics, but when I put more then one, the last one doesn't work.

The Morris call is:

```
<div id="graphT"></div>
```

And, the JS is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Morris.Donut({
    element: 'graphT',
    data: [
    {value: 50, label: '05'},
    {value: 10, label: '07'},
    {value: 40, label: '07'},
    ],
    labelColor: '#000',
    colors: [
    '#ae1c1c',
    '#000',
    '#cc9a00'
    ],
    formatter: function (x) { return x + "%"}
  }).on('click', function(i, row){
    console.log(i, row);
  });
  </script>
```

Now the whole code:

```
<div id="graphT"></div>
<div id="TD"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  Morris.Donut({
    element: 'graphT',
    data: [
    {value: 50, label: '05'},
    {value: 10, label: '07'},
    {value: 40, label: '07'},
    ],
    labelColor: '#000',
    colors: [
    '#ae1c1c',
    '#000',
    '#cc9a00'
    ],
    formatter: function (x) { return x + "%"}
  }).on('click', function(i, row){
    console.log(i, row);
  });
  </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  Morris.Donut({
    element: 'TD',
    data: [
    {value: 50, label: '05'},
    {value: 10, label: '07'},
    {value: 40, label: '07'},
    ],
    labelColor: '#000',
    colors: [
    '#ae1c1c',
    '#000',
    '#cc9a00'
    ],
    formatter: function (x) { return x + "%"}
  }).on('click', function(i, row){
    console.log(i, row);
  });
  </script>
```

Anyone have an idea about what's happening? I can't put it on JsFille, because needs the Morris library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be working just fine for me... [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8LXF/)

Comment: Also note that you can include external resources on jsfiddle

Comment: Show both graphs there?

Comment: On my machine it does.  What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also import morris.js' dependencies ? They are `raphael.js` and `jQuery`.